# Buttons Animation android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

I'm sorry English is not my first language but I will try my best
I'm new to Android and I need your help.
I have twenty button I want each button moves differently from the other button in the sense that each button has a different movement. I use one animation for all buttons.

```
...
Button but1,but2,but3,but4,but5,but6,but7,but8,but9,but10,
       but11,but12,but13,but14,but15,but16,but17,but18,but19,but20,

Animation ani;
...
ani = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanimation);

but1.setAnimation(ani);but2.setAnimation(ani);
but3.setAnimation(ani);...
```

Do you create 20 file xml animation and each file has its movement or is there another way
thank you

Comment: If you are using transition animation you can define transition animation programmatically and use it.

Comment: Thank you but how